# How to organize React Dynamic Components with state-based props

Tags: reactjs

I need to show specific Components based on state. In order to do this, I created an object that defines what Component to display based on the active tab index. This object, however, is going to be huge and I don't want it to take up thousands of lines in `App.js`. However, many of the props that these dynamic Components need are derived from App's state. Is there any way I could pull `components` out into its own js file and still access App's state and functions to set the props?

In App.js:

```
components = () => {
        return {
            Standard: {
                0: {
                    comp: StandardOverview,
                    props: {
                        overview: this.state.overview,
                        enroll: this.doEnroll
                    }
                },
                1: {
                    comp: AccountActivity,
                    props: {
                        account: this.props.account,
                        accountData: this.state.accountData
                    }
                }
            },
            Special: {
                0: {
                    comp: SpecialOverview,
                    props: {
                        overview: this.state.overview,
                        enroll: this.doEnrollSpecial
                    }
                },
                1: {
                    comp: Communications,
                    props: {
                        subscriptions: this.state.subscriptions,
                        mobilePhone: this.state.mobilePhone,
                        onSubscribeClick: this.onSubscribeClick
                    }
                }
          }
       }
};

render() {
    const contentForIndex = this.components()[this.state.profileType || "Standard"][this.state.activeIndex];
        const ContentComponent = contentForIndex.comp;
        const props = contentForIndex.props;
        return (
            <ErrorHandler>
                <ContentComponent {...props} />
            </ErrorHandler>
        )
}
```

Comment: You could use react router. Basically react hijacks browser history, and you can render different components based on URL. `/home` => `StandardOverview`, `/account/` => `AccountActivity` etc

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it slightly differently.  Instead of having `components` return an object, why not just convert it into a react component that uses a switch to return the correct child component based on props to `component`?

Like this:

```
components = props => {
        switch(props.yourMainKey){
             case 'standard':
                 return (
                     <StandardOverview 
                         overview={props.overview} 
                         {...anyOtherProps} 
                     />
                 )
             case 'Special':
                 return (
                     <SpecialOverview overview={props.overview} />
                 )
             default:
                 return (
                     <DefaultView overview={props.defaultProps} />
                 )
        }
}
```

Comment: This really doesn't help me because then I'd need nested switch statements. Not only do I need to know whether the profileType is Standard or Special (or 10 other values), but I also need to know what the active tab is. It's basically the same as having my giant object except now I have a giant switch statement.

Comment: Yes but with a giant switch statement you are able to remove one level of nesting because the switch is a react component itself, plus it solves the question you asked: 'Is there any way I could pull components out into its own js file'.  If you don't want to deal with a giant component or object then use a routing library, it is what they were intended for.